# Why won't my File.dat be read and run and how can I assign the data to a struct? - C

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

**ISSUE:** I'm new to C, and even newer to `structs`, when I try to simply print out my data within the beer.dat file, I'm presented with an error and I know that I'm not reading it properly, but how can I store my data within my Struct once the file is streaming properly?

For full clarity, I'll post the assignment questions...
The assignment is to:

1. Searching for a beer should prompt the user for an ID number and the result should display its
   quantity and price, if it is in your inventory.
2. A view of the entire inventory will display all the beers with their ID number, price and
   quantity in ascending order by price. This sorting should be done using either Recursive
   Bubble or Recursive Selection sort.
3. When placing an order an invoice of the order should be printed to the screen.

**The beer.dat file contents:**

```
7 // total number of beers 
Coors //beer name
1234567 // beer id
72 // beer quantity
7.40 //beer price 
Miller
7777777
44
9.70
Bud
7654321
345
9.90
Wachusett
7799435
4
14.70
Corona
9999999
112
9.99
Zima
0000000
1
0.01
Mikes
0890398
12
10.99
```

**CODE:**

```
#include "beer.dat" //loading required file... in other news - making groundbreaking comments like this because I'm forced to, stay tuned!
#include <stdio.h> // including the thing
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct beerData {
    char *beer[7]; // number of brands

    char *beer_name; //names
    int beer_id[7]; //ID number given to beer
    int beer_quantity; //stock
    float beer_price; // pricing
} beer_data;

int main() {
    int user_choice;
    printf("Enter 1 to search for a beer, 2 to view the entire catalogue,"
           " and 3 to place an order, press 4 to exit.\n");
    scanf("%d", &user_choice);

    while (user_choice != 4) {
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Searching for a beer\n");
                search();
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Viewing Inventory\n");
                //viewInv();
                break;
            case 3:

                printf("Placing an order...\n");
                //placeOrder();
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("Incorrect entry, try again.\n");
                continue;
        }
    }


}

void search() {
    //look through beer.dat for a specific beer by ID number.

    FILE *fp = fopen("beer.dat", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error: can't open file to read\n");
    } else {
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s ", fp);
            //printStr(fp);
        }


    }

    fclose(fp);
}

void printStr(char *line) {
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

**INITIAL ERRORS:** The compiler is giving me,

```
In file included from C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\work\main.c:32:0:
C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\work\beer.dat:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
 7
 ^
C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\work\beer.dat:27:1: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
 0890398
 ^~~~~~~
```

I truly appreciate any assistance you can provide. I'm in the middle of a major depression episode, and because of that I'm having a very difficult time understanding this new concept. This is the final assignment of the semester. Again, I truly thank you for taking a look at this issue. Not asking to complete the assignment of course!!

Comment: @user10605163 I apologize, I have all of those includes at the top, I forgot to copy the struct as well. I will edit with the warnings/errors too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your program to read stuff from `beer.dat` when it is executing. The file does not include code that is part of your program. The compiler is telling you that it doesn't know how to interpret the stuff in the file as part of a C program.

So remove the line `#include "beer.dat"`.

The file is opened and read later in `search` with `fopen` and `fscanf`.

You are also still missing the forward-declaration for `search`. Either put the `search` function before `main` or add a declaration like

```
void search();
```

before `main`, so that the compiler knows what arguments `search` takes and what it returns, when you call it in `main`.

Enabling some extra warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` also tells us that

```
<source>: In function 'search':
<source>:58:26: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'FILE *' {aka 'struct _IO_FILE *'} [-Wformat=]
             fscanf(fp, "%s ", fp);
                         ~^    ~~
<source>:58:13: warning: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3 [-Wrestrict]
             fscanf(fp, "%s ", fp);
             ^~~~~~
```

because you are trying to read from the file that the handler `fp` (first argument) refers to, and you are instructing `fscanf` to save the string read to where the file handler `fp` is pointing (the third argument). Of course that doesn't make any sense, you want to save it in some `char` array.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Once I hit the `search` function, my compiler crashes. Any idea why?

Comment: @user7823016 "Chrashes" and "Once I hit" are kind of vague. If you have a different compilation error now, then it would be best to make a new question and again post the complete error message there. If it is a runtime chrash, then use a debugger to figure out exactly where the program crashes. Also enable more warnings in your compiler, e.g. with `-Wall -Wextra` command line options to the compiler. It will tell you about at least another issue.

Comment: well no I understand, my issue hasn't been fully resolved yet. Once I run through main, and select the `search` function, all I'm given is `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 `

Comment: @user7823016 Read my edit to the answer if you haven't. I don't see any other reason for a runtime crash as the code is now.

Comment: the warning is `Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct _iobuf *')` when referring to the third field in the `fscanf` line in `search`. Also I did step through the debugger, and I'm not sure how to enable those warnings in CLion

Comment: @user7823016 Yes, as I explained your third argument to `fscanf` should be a pointer to a `char` array.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought you were talking about an edit you made to one of your comments.